# difference between single and double quotes in printf() in C

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

I have question regarding usage of double and single 
quotes in printf() of C. I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buffer[100];
    strncpy(buffer, argv[1], 100);
    printf(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

so when I compile and run it following results happen:

```
./a.out 'AAAA%8$p'

AAAA0x70243825**41414141**

./o "AAAA%8$p"

AAAA
```

Notice in first case I inputted the single quotes and in the latter, double quotes.

What is happening here.

Q2. I am following this link [here](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/02/introduction-to-format-string-exploits.html). So my question is how come AAAA in the input, argv[1] while running, is able to influence of output of printf(). First I thought this was a mere coincidence but I inputted and got the following

```
./o 'BBBB%8$p'

BBBB0x70243825**42424242**
```

Edit: So I think there is some misunderstanding seeing the answer. I know about the misuse of the direct "printf(buffer)". So I am going to quote the link I referred to earlier in question:

*Since printf has a variable number of arguments, it must use the format string to determine the number of arguments. In the case above, the attacker can pass the string "%p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p" and fool the printf into thinking it has 15 arguments. It will naively print the next 15 addresses on the stack, thinking they are its arguments:*

```
$ ./a.out "%p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p"
0xffffdddd 0x64 0xf7ec1289 0xffffdbdf 0xffffdbde (nil) 0xffffdcc4 0xffffdc64 (nil) 0x25207025 0x70252070 0x20702520 0x25207025 0x70252070 0x20702520
```

*At about 10 arguments up the stack, we can see a repeating pattern of 0x252070 - those are our %ps on the stack! We start our string with AAAA to see this more explicitly:*

```
$ ./a.out "AAAA%p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p"
AAAA0xffffdde8 0x64 0xf7ec1289 0xffffdbef 0xffffdbee (nil) 0xffffdcd4 0xffffdc74 (nil) 0x41414141
```

*The 0x41414141 is the hex representation of AAAA. We now have a way to pass an arbitrary value (in this case, we're passing 0x41414141) as an argument to printf. At this point we will take advantage of another format string feature: in a format specifier, we can also select a specific argument. For example, printf("%2$x", 1, 2, 3) will print 2. In general, we can do printf("%$x") to select an arbitrary argument to printf. In our case, we see that 0x41414141 is the 10th argument to printf, so we can simplify our string1:*

```
$ ./a.out 'AAAA%10$p'
AAAA0x41414141
```

So I don't really think it is the garbage value. Rather it is infact a address of the location.

My platform: Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit machine.

So I want to know how 'AAAA' or 'BBBB' in the input are having an effect in the output 'AAAA0x70243825**41414141**' or BBBB0x70243825**42424242**.

Comment: This has nothing to do with printf. It is to do with the shel

Comment: Look up what your command shell does with single and double quotes.   It will do those things before even executing your program - but that will affect the data your program is given.    Different shells do different things though.

Comment: Don't use `printf(str)` to print a string. That's extremely dangerous if there's a format identifier in the string. Use `printf("%s", str)` instead. The parameter passing is done by the shell. It has no relation to C whatsoever. Try running that in Windows and it won't work like that

Comment: why the downvote???.....

Comment: Could be because questions tagged [tag:c] are generally about how to write *good* C code, not how to reverse-engineer a *bad* one. You might get better luck on [RE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with quotes in C. *shell* removes both single and double quotes from your command line argument. But shell may also apply special meaning to the dollar sign (`$p` might get expanded by the shell before it is passed to your application if you use double quotes, but not single quotes).

So this: `./a.out 'AAAA%8$p'` passes in `AAAA%8$p` as `argv[1]`, and this: `./a.out "AAAA%8$p"` *probably* passes in `AAAA%8` (if the `p` environment variable is not defined).

Now about the strange output that you're seeing.

`printf`, being a [cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) function, has no way to know how many arguments you passed to it. So it *expects* you to pass as many arguments as there are placeholders in the format string.

Then the stack would look like:

[image: 1]

But you don't provide enough arguments. So *your* stack looks more like:

[image: 2]

What happens then is - `printf` reads the memory where the arguments are *supposed to be*, and hits the locals of `main()`, i.e. `buffer`.

Then it reads 8 bytes from there and prints them in hex (`%p` prints out a pointer in hex format, and in your case pointer size is 8 bytes).

`A` in hex is `41`, that's why you see 4 times 41, the same for `B` which is hex `42`.

That's *undefined behavior*. It should not be relied upon (unless you're writing an exploit). It will change between platforms, compilers or even optimization modes.

In general, you want to stay in the realm of *defined behavior*.

p.s. In addition to the dangers of incorrectly using `printf` which you apparently are aware of, you might also want to check the edge cases such as no argument provided or input too long.

Comment: "You need fputs or puts" Or use `printf("%s",buffer);`

Comment: then why it's not "AAAA%8" printed... and for the second part it's not garbage value. It's the address of the location of variables stored in the stack. See the edited question.

Comment: Actually, `%8$p` is a well-defined printf specifier -- it means print the 8th argument after the format as a pointer.  Its undefined becuase you don't give it 8 arguments after the format, nor to you use/specify the first 7 arguments.

Comment: If you try to print this as printf("%8$p"), you will get an address. It means this command prints the location of the 8th variable in stack. In general,  printf("%<n>$p") will print the n'th location of stack variable.

Answer (score -1):

printf (buffer) is very, very, very dangerous.

The first argument of printf is a format string, containing text, but also format specifiers like %d to print integers, %s to print strings and so on.

If buffer contains a format specifier, then printf will try to process the next arguments after the format string according to the format specifier. But you are not passing any other arguments, and you wouldn't know what arguments to pass anyway. So you get undefined behaviour.

In practice,

```
char buffer [100];
strcpy (buffer, "%s");
printf (buffer);
```

is very, very likely to crash.